# is naming syntax mandatory for APIKit router To route requests to specific flows where the flow mapping is defined?

Tags: mule, apikit

To route requests to specific flows where the flow mapping is defined with APIKit router, is naming syntax mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

For the auto-generate flow mappings yes. However you can override these via :

```
<apikit:config name="apiConfig" raml="api.raml" doc:name="Router" >
   <apikit:flow-mapping resource="/resourceOne" action="get" flow-ref="someFlowOfYours"/>
</apikit:config>
```